# How to fix "Error in m$getDat() : attempt to apply non-function" when estimating xmin for poweRlaw

Tags: r, power-law

I'm trying to fit a power law distribution to some sample data. I am trying to find xmin using the `estimate_xmin()` function. Does anyone know why I get an error about attempting to apply a non-function?

```
abs.logreturns <- as.data.frame(t(abs.logreturns))
x <- abs.logreturns
estimate_xmin(x, xmins = NULL, pars = NULL, xmax = 1e+05, distance = "ks")
```

Error message:

```
Error in m$getDat() : attempt to apply non-function
```

Comment: Hi, you need to make your question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038) for Stack Overflow, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a vector to the `estimate_xmin()` - it needs to be a powerlaw object. See the Getting Started and/or Worked examples vignettes in the poweRlaw package - https://github.com/csgillespie/poweRlaw